# My form isn't going to the post route even tho I'm listing the correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

or at least I think its the correct path.  This is the error I'm getting:

No route matches [POST] "/terms/new"

And this is my code:

```
<h1>New Terms</h1>

<%= form_for :term, url: terms_path do |t| %>
<p>
    <%= t.label :term %><br>
    <%= t.text_field :term %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= t.label :definition %><br>
    <%= t.text_field :definition %>
</p>
    <%= t.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and this is my rake routes

```
    terms GET    /terms(.:format)          terms#index
          POST   /terms(.:format)          terms#create
 new_term GET    /terms/new(.:format)      terms#new
edit_term GET    /terms/:id/edit(.:format) terms#edit
     term GET    /terms/:id(.:format)      terms#show
          PATCH  /terms/:id(.:format)      terms#update
          PUT    /terms/:id(.:format)      terms#update
          DELETE /terms/:id(.:format)      terms#destroy
```

Putting the url to terms_path in my form should send the object to the terms/create if I'm not mistaken?  Obviously still a rails newbie here.  Help!

This is also my controller if that helps

```
  def new
    @term = Term.new(params[:term])
  end
```

Comment: Try changing `form_for :term` to `form_for @term`. Not sure it will help but worth a shot. Otherwise your form might be nested inside another set of form tags, for instance if your view is a partial there might be another `form_for` in the parent template which is wrapping it. Lastly it's always worth restarting your server (and stopping Spring if you're using Rails 4.1) just to make sure.

Comment: Your form HTML works. I can't reproduce this issue with what you've provided. Try posting more of your code and the versions of ruby / rails you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing to 'terms_path', try:

```
<%= form_for @term, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

PS: If you're just getting your feet wet with Rails & RESTful/CRUD basics, you can try generating a scaffold on the CLI to see exactly the right code for this sort of thing (on your CLI):

```
rails g scaffold term
```